# How to separate javascript and markup in case of a script line with parameters?

Tags: javascript

Separating javascript and markup is easy when the script doesn't have parameters. But how is it done with inline script lines that do? Example:

```
<td class="input-cell">
    <input type="radio" name="action-type" id="change-add" value="change-add" 
    onclick="showSelectTables('none','none','none','table','none','none')">
</td>

(....)

<script>
function showSelectTables(set1a,set1b,set1c,setSetup,set2,set3) {
    var _1a = document.getElementById('careSelector');
    _1a.style.display = set1a;
    var _1b = document.getElementById('module-I');
    _1b.style.display = set1b;
    var _1c = document.getElementById('clarificSection');
    _1c.style.display = set1c;
    var setup = document.getElementById('setup');
    setup.style.display = setSetup;
    var _2 = document.getElementById('module-II');
    _2.style.display = set2;
    var _3 = document.getElementById('module-III');
    _3.style.display = set3;
}
</script>
```

.

I've tried all varieties I can think of, but all I'm getting is error reports, 'undefined' or the silent treatment from the browser. Is it possible at all, and if so, how? I would be looking for a vanilla javascript solution.

EDIT: see here for what I'm trying to achieve: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript, section 2.

Comment: Question: where does the parameters (`'none','none','none','table','none','none'`) come from?

Comment: Post the error messages. Other then that -- I don't understand your questions. I don't know what you mean by "separating js and markup".

Comment: Your code works in an isolated jsFiddle, your issue must be elsewhere in your code/markup. http://jsfiddle.net/L87Vf/

Comment: At Raptor: on occasion the html, including the inline script line, is generated dynamically. That's why I would like the scripts to be separated from the markup as much as possible. At Mihai and Nit: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript.

Comment: Consider generating an multi-dimensional array of parameters in JS when you generate the HTML, and associate them with unique ID

Comment: At the downvoters: ridiculous action! This is an honest question about a fairly new principle, which is important in case of dynamically generated HTML. If you don't know an answer or don't even understand the question, that means that it is out of your league, but that does not give you the right to downvote the question whatsoever. @Raptor: how would that look in a practical example? The devil being in the details with javascript, and me having spent some three hours on it already, I could use such an example.

Comment: 1. I didn't downvote; 2. the principle is not a new thing (e.g. jQuery is using it for many years); 3. 3 hours on JS is not much, really; 4. Can you show how do you "generate" your HTML ?

Comment: @Raptor: I wasn't 'talking' to you, because I didn't think you were one of the downvoters. I appreciate your responses. The HTML is generated with AJAX/PHP/MySQL, and its form depends on previously made choices by the user. The example I gave is just a simple example, to facilitate an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your HTML generation logic to generate the followings:

```
<td class="input-cell">
    <input type="radio" name="action-type" id="change-add" value="change-add" />
</td>

<script>
// just show 2 variables for demo
var settings = { change-add : { set1a: 'some_value', set1b: 'some_value' } }

$('#change-add').click(function() {
    showSelectTables($(this).attr('id'));
});
function showSelectTables(the_id) {
    var set1a = settings[the_id]['set1']; // which returns 'some_value'
    // similar for set1b,set1c,setSetup,set2,set3

    var _1a = document.getElementById('careSelector');
    _1a.style.display = set1a;
    var _1b = document.getElementById('module-I');
    _1b.style.display = set1b;
    var _1c = document.getElementById('clarificSection');
    _1c.style.display = set1c;
    var setup = document.getElementById('setup');
    setup.style.display = setSetup;
    var _2 = document.getElementById('module-II');
    _2.style.display = set2;
    var _3 = document.getElementById('module-III');
    _3.style.display = set3;
}
</script>
```

Note: this assumes you use jQuery.

---

An important note: there is nothing wrong to use inline onclick, but it's a better pattern to separate JS and HTML

Comment: As said, I appreciate your responses. But to have to use jQuery just for this - the rest of the JS coding I do in vanilla - is going too far for me. Like I stated in the original post: I would be looking for a vanilla javascript solution.

Comment: Consider switching to jQuery, as it is more common, more power, more users. For the above codes, switching back to standard JS is not difficult.